# Best way to store 900000 records when binding the telerik radgrid with custom paging

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-enterprise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binding 800000 records in Radgrid throwing timeout error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21042/binding-800000-records-in-radgrid-throwing-timeout-error)

I am creating sample application in SharePoint 2010, i want to load 900000 records in Telerik RadGrid, so first i am storing all 900000 records in ViewState and get the 50 records from ViewState and bind it in RadGrid due to the performance issue, but the page size goes to very huge, so it's throwing page timeout error, after that i store the 900000 records in `SPWeb` property bag instead of storing in ViewState event hough it's throwing the same error, can anyone help me please.
 where i can able to store those (900000) values with out any timeout issue or performance issue, please help me

Comment: This is the third time you've posted questions that are off topic or essentially a duplicate. Consider this your last warning.

Answer (score -1):

If your intended data size is 900,000 records then SharePoint is probably not the best place to manage this data as that is *well* beyond the recommendations of the product.  It certainly can hold that many but it is not a good idea and will not perform well.

However, you could simply keep this data in a SQL database and then access it as an External List though I'm not sure how well the RADGrid works with external lists.

In either case, I seriously doubt any real user would page through 900,000 records so there isn't really a need to keep this data that close to the user (i.e. cached in WFE or viewstate)

Comment: I'm adding this in here, because the 'duplicate' thread was closed as being off topic. SharePoint can easily handle 900,000 records in a List. It all depends on the methods you use to get to that data. If you query & paginate properly, either by using SPQuery, SPSiteDataQuery or even the Search APIs (probably recommended with a list this size) you can quickly and efficiently return records in a list of any size. This is because all 900,000 wouldn't be cached on a WFE or ViewState.